# Run vagrant box in background without a prompt

Tags: vagrant

I have a Cassandra instance running inside virtualbox using vagrant in my windows PC, And my other dev/application settings are in another VM. I don't always need a prompt/UI/CI for the cassandra vm because it's confusing to switch between, is there a way to bring the vagrant without a UI/CI prompt?

Now i'm ding `vagrant up`

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I follow, when you run `vagrant up` the VM is started but there's no prompt , this is only there after you run `vagrant ssh`

Comment: can you please point me while image you are using, I'm using the boxccutter-centos-7( https://app.vagrantup.com/box-cutter/boxes/centos72)